# Where are my Plasma add-ons going (Kubuntu 16.10)?

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10, plasma-5

I have observed a strange behavior Kubuntu 16.10. When I go to install an add-on (themes, widgets), I can access the list of available for download (so no server issues). I click install and the add-on installs yet I cannot locate it anywhere to use it. EDIT: wallpapers appear as expected though!

**Specific case:** installing the Thermal Monitor widget for CPU temperatures.

1. Click top left menu (three horizontal bars - what's this called?) and Add Widgets
2. At the bottom of the widgets list click Get New Widgets, then Download New Plasma Widgets
3. 

[image: Image of available widgets]

  4.

[image: Shows Thermal Monitor installed]

I expected after this that the widget would appear in the menu of widgets to add to the desktop. It doesn't. Where does it go? Has it silently failed to install? This has to be my simple lack of experience with Kubuntu but I can't figure it out.